# Composer autoload doesn't find class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, classnotfound

H, my composer json file autoload with psr-4 a Class, but when a Call that Class, php return error: `Error: Class 'ClassA\Tae' not found`

Here json autoload

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ClassA\\": "includes/ClassA/",
        "": "includes/"
    }
}
```

and my php class that require ClassA is this

```
require_once __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use ClassA\{ Rate, Tae, Taeg };

   class TestTaeg extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

  public function test_tae() {
        $obj = Tae::init( 5, 12 );
}
```

Do you know why I cannot find ClassA ?

I run the code with phpunit on cli, with this syntax (is the first time that I use phpunit)

```
../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit ./test-general.php
```

Thx

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried composer dump-autoload   but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

Are you namespacing your classes right ? To be honest your psr-4 autoloading looks a bit messy, I am asuming you are autoloading everything even when you dont need those.

So if you please share a screenshot of your folder structure, I can try to recreate your issue and probably suggest a solution.

Comment: Thank you NH,
here is my folder tree:

| tests
   --  bootstrap.php
   --  test.php
| vendor
  --   autoload.php
  --   bin
  --   composer
  --   doctrine
  --   myclabs
  --   phar-io
  --   phpdocumentor
  --   phpspec
  --   phpunit
  --   sebastian
  --   theseer
  --   webmozart

Comment: I dont see a "includes" folder in your tree which you mentioned in your composer autoloading. Please check that and also it would be nice to get an ACTUAL tree like view of your folder structure.

Comment: yes, you're right. I've added that folder yesterday but nothing ha chaged.
So, Now I've this tree (root)
| tests  | vendor  | includes -- ClassA ---- Tae (this is the name of the class that I call in my test.php file   use ClassA\{Tae};  )